# NodeList shows item, but unable to access items

Tags: javascript, nodelist, getelementsbyname

I am trying to get an Input by its name attribute, and change the Input's value attribute to something else.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
var utmEle = document.getElementsByName(fieldName);
if(utmEle) {
    console.log(utmEle);
    utmEle.value = fieldValue;
    console.log(utmEle);
    console.log(utmEle[0]);
}
```

Whenever I preview the console logs, this is what is being returned:

[image]

[image]

From what I've read online, I should be able to access the only item in the NodeList using `utmEle[0]`, however, this comes back undefined.

More so, whenever I console log `utmEle.length`, the length is returned as `0`. Any advice or suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Sincerely,

Blaine H.

Comment: Can you share the HTML too?

Comment: What happens if you remove this line `utmEle.value = fieldValue;`?

Comment: @FortuneEkeruo would just the HTML for the Input be okay? I cannot send the entire HTML file.

Comment: @Musa I included that line to see if I could add a property to the NodeList and successfully view the change. If I remove that line, NodeList remains the same, but I'm still unable to access the [0]th item in it.

Comment: What environment are you running this code?

Comment: @Musa I'd like to use GTM to deploy the JS. I've also tried placing the code in the footer file on WP.

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a (soft) array. So what do you think `utmEle.value = fieldValue;` tries to update? Also, NodeList objects are _live views_ on your document. Usually you want to at the very least do `let res = Array.from( <code that yields a nodelist> )` so you can use normal array operations.

Answer (score 0):

NodeLists are live views on a document. Iterating over them is pretty much always bad code, because iteration requires a deterministically stable list, which NodeList absolutely is not (if a node is removed from the DOM, your NodeList immediately updates accordingly).

Instead, you want to use `Array.from` and then iterate normally:

```
let elements = document.getElementsByName('...');
let stable = Array.from(elements);
stable.forEach(element => {
  element.value = 'whatever you needed it to be';
});
```